# "The JavaScript runtime exited unexpectedly" Error when Uploading PDF File to Google Cloud Storage Bucket with Google Apps Script

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script, file-upload, google-cloud-storage, runtime-error

I'm facing an issue while attempting to upload a PDF file to a Google Cloud Storage bucket using Google Apps Script. Despite ensuring that my file size (28MB) is within the allowed [quota](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/services/quotas#current_limitations) (50MB) for the URLFetch call size for Google apps script, I'm consistently receiving the error message "The JavaScript runtime exited unexpectedly."

```
function uploadToGCS(fileBlob, index) {
  var service = getService();

  if (!service.hasAccess()) {
    Logger.log("Please authorize %s", service.getAuthorizationUrl());
    return;
  }

  var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.openById('sheetId').getSheets()[0]

  var fileName = sheet.getRange(params.CLIENT_FILE_COLUMN + index).getValue()
  fileName = fileName.replace(/,|&|\//gi, "-");

  var sheetLinkCellValue = sheet.getRange(params.SHEET_LINK_COLUMN + index).getValue().toString().split('/')
  var txtFileBlob = Utilities.newBlob(sheetLinkCellValue[5]);
  txtFileBlob.setName(fileName);

  console.log("Uploading to text  Bucket");
  var txtUrl = 'https://www.googleapis.com/upload/storage/v1/b/BUCKET/o?uploadType=media&name=FILE'
    .replace("BUCKET", params.TXT_BUCKET_NAME)
    .replace("FILE", fileName + '.txt');

  var txtResponse = UrlFetchApp.fetch(txtUrl, {
    method: "POST",
    contentLength: txtFileBlob.getBytes().length,
    contentType: 'application/txt',
    payload: txtFileBlob.getBytes(),
    headers: {
      Authorization: 'Bearer ' + service.getAccessToken()
    }
  });
  var txtResult = JSON.parse(txtResponse.getContentText());
  Logger.log(txtResult)

  var pdfUrl = 'https://www.googleapis.com/upload/storage/v1/b/BUCKET/o?uploadType=media&name=FILE'
    .replace("BUCKET", params.PDF_BUCKET_NAME)
    .replace("FILE", fileName + '.pdf');

  var bytes = fileBlob.getBytes();

  Logger.log('URL fetched successfully');

  // My Script fails and give me this error in the Next fetch

  var pdfResponse = UrlFetchApp.fetch(pdfUrl, {
    method: "POST",
    contentLength: bytes.length,
    contentType: fileBlob.getContentType(),
    payload: bytes,
    headers: {
      Authorization: 'Bearer ' + service.getAccessToken()
    }
  });
  console.log("Uploaded to PDF Bucket!!!!");
  var pdfResult = JSON.parse(pdfResponse.getContentText());
  console.log(pdfResult)
}
```

What could be the potential cause of this error,
I appreciate any insights or suggestions on how to resolve this issue. Thank you!

Comment: Have you checked your execution logs to check how long your execution time is? You could probably log each method as well to check where it further stems down.

Comment: I checked yeah, but seems normal because some other executions take double or even triple the time this one takes to get the error, Thanks btw